# Javascript AJAX strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

I've got something like this:

```
elFinder.prototype.commands.info = function()
{
    this.exec = function(hashes)
    {
        var temp_array = new Array(),
            temp_html = new String();
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        request.onload = function()
        {
            temp_html = "<a href='foo'>bar</a>";
            temp_array.push(temp_html);
            alert("Outside - Array size is " + temp_array.length); 
        }
        request.open("get", "foo.com/url", true);
        request.send();
        alert("Outside - Array size is " + temp_array.length); 
    }
}
```

Which prints, respectively:

> Inside - Array size is 1

and

> Outside - Array size is 0

Somehow "losing" the array content.

Comment: ajax is asynchronous. your `outside` alert is running **BEFORE** the request ever has a chance to reach the server.

Comment: ofc, but the weird thing was that, only in Firefox, my desired behaviour was correctly obtained. So consequences are, *in general*, undefined.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is inside `AJAX` concept itself. In particular, `true` into

```
request.open("get", "foo.com/url", true);
```

means that the request should be treated in an asynchronous way (btw, the suggested mode into the main thread environment, as browsers like Chrome deprecate synchronous requests for the huge latency they usually carry).

The insight was provided by the different order in the `alert()` series, testing the snippet first in Firefox and then in Chrome.

In my context I strictly needed a synchronous behaviour, so I switched to `false` the boolean flag.